# FIrst time writing ASP.NET MVC app- need to tie to SSRS and display reports

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, reporting

Hey everyone.. This is my first time writing an ASP.NET MVC web app, and it's going good.  I have no problems there.  What I don't have any experience in is SSRS though.  Ultimately I want to be able to render reports on my ASP.NET MVC app.

1. I got the report server installed and running, and it's visible within SQL Server Management Studio.
2. I created a test report (.rdl) via Business Intelligence Development Studio, and published it to my report server.  It's now there, I checked.

My question is how do I tie that into my main application?  Do I have to add a reference in my main application to be able to retrieve the report I created?  I'm totally lost- I have my main database and my report server both visible within SQL Server Management Studio.  That's as far as I got... help????  Thanks in advance..!

Comment: If I have answered your question, can you please tick my answer. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  I marked your answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx

Failing that, if you are new to ASP.NET MVC and you do not specifically require MS Reporting Services (`.rdl`) created through BI Development Studio, but are satisfied with a standard Visual Studio Report (`.rdlc`) (This simply means the report may be more or less linked only to the single app.  You create these via Visual Studio Project - Right Click -> New Item -> Reporting -> Report) take a look at this link (http://www.danielroot.info/2009/06/how-to-render-reporting-services.html), even though it states how to link Reporting Services, he actually means standard reporting `.rdlc` files.  In essence it publishes simply the output from an `.rdlc` report as a `.pdf` and stream it to your user, I have found it to be incredibly simply and a powerful way to quickly publish reports.

Failing that a hybrid of both implementations might allow you to stream your Reporting Service `.rdl` correctly.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response!  I'll give that a shot.  So what reporting architecture is your first suggestion using?  Crystal Reports?  I might be asking the wrong question.

Comment: The first one is using Sql Server Reporting Services, but the second is just using the plain `.rdlc` VS .NET winform/webapp client-side reporting.