# How to deploy or show a SSRS report in asp.net page using c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have made a SSRS report with is showing all the desired data when i am running the report but when i am trying see on the browser by

```
http://localhost/Reporting/SSRSTestReport
```

its giving me an error

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been
>   removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily        unavailable.

and when I am trying to show it in `aspx` page its giving me an error like this :

```
The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information   and that the report server is a compatible version.
The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
```

now i am doing this in `aspx.cs` page :

```
 try
    {
        IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials("sa", "arindam", "ITPL_PC1");
        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/Reporting/SSRSTestReport");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "D:\\SSRSTest\\SSRSTest\\SSRSTest\\SSRSTestReport";
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.ToString());
    }
```

the `CustomReportCredentials` I have taken from here : [Passing Credentials to Sql Report Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671694/passing-credentials-to-sql-report-server-2008)

this is my `http handler` in my web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
        <remove path="*.asmx" verb="*"/>
        <add path="*.asmx" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add path="*_AppService.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add path="ScriptResource.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Please help me to solve this thing , I know I am missing something but couldn't find it

Comment: Seems you are missing `axd` entries in your web.config. Share the section regarding http handlers and I can tell you what you are missing.

Comment: can show me what i am missing.

Comment: Paste the http handlers from your web.config into the question

Comment: yeah i did. pls check it now

Comment: Your settings are valid only for IIS6. What version of IIS?

Comment: mine is IIS7.5 so what should i do?

Comment: Possible duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599991/first-time-writing-asp-net-mvc-app-need-to-tie-to-ssrs-and-display-reports

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your setting in the `system.webServer` section

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" 
    type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

Refer: [How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: the http handler is in the `system.web` section and its the same as before i guess